# Parsing an array from recursion function C++

Tags: c++, arrays

So I a little new to C++ and discovery what I can and can't do in comparison to python. Basically I have a function and inside that function I want to parse through an array and some integers run it, and return the output number. But it seems to prove a little tricky. Wondering where I am messing up.

Since the function it contains in is dominated by recursion I can't just make it a global variable where the array values are static.

So here is an outline of the code

```
void sequenceAlignment(int iStart,int jStart,int kStart, int seqLen1Size, int seqLen2Size, int seqLen3Size) {

int lengthi = seqLen1Size - iStart;
int lengthj = seqLen2Size - jStart;
int lengthk = seqLen3Size - kStart;
/* Sets it as a floor */
int midpoint = (seqLen1Size + iStart) / 2;

/*End the recursion*/
if (lengthi <= 1)
    return;

/*We set two scoring arrays and intialize the XY Plane in the 3D */
int forwardScore[2][lengthj + 1][lengthk + 1];
int backwardsScore[2][lengthj + 1][lengthk + 1];


/* Some code */ and then to this 
forwardSubscoringCalculation(multidimensionalarray, int, int, int, int, int, int)
```

The Function that is being called

```
void forwardSubscoringCalculation(int forwardScore, int scorei, int scorej, int scorek, int scoredArrayi, int scoredArrayj, int scoredArrayk) {

    int tempValueHolder = 0;
    int subscore[3] = {-10000, -10000, -10000};

    subscore[0] = forwardScore[scorei][scorej][scorek] + scoredArray[scoredArrayi][scoredArrayj][scoredArrayk];
}
```

I am wondering how can I exactly do this. I thought by setting up the array it also acts like a pointer and be passed through but I might screwing that up. Is it possible in this code or can it be quite tricky?

**EDIT  Minimal Code**

```
void score(int, int, int, int, int, int, int);
void function(int, int ,int, int, int, int)


void function(int i, int j, int k, int l, int m, int n) {

    int forward[Number][Number][Number];
    for (x = 0; x >= l; x++){
        score(forward, i + x, j, k l, m n)  
    }
}

void score(int array, value1, value2, value3, value4, value 5, value6){
          /* Do some stuff with the array */
}
```

Comment: _"Wondering where I am messing up."_ Where are you messing up? Can you elaborate about that a bit more please? Error messages, exceptions, unexpected output?

Comment: Don't use raw arrays and pointers in c++ code BTW.

Comment: Sure I am getting a compiling error that I can pass the array through when calling the forwardSubscoringCalculation that the forwardScore is not an array. I tried changing it to forwardScore[][][] but can't pass an empty array. So wondering if there was a simple way to get the code correct.

Comment: Why is that bad code for raw arrays and pointers?

Comment: Post a [MCVE] including the verbatim error message text.

Comment: _"Why is that bad code for raw arrays and pointers?"_ I didn't say it is bad code, I said just don't use them in c++ YAGNI.

Comment: Okay, I made edits and if i gets across my point?

Comment: That's still far from a [MCVE]. Read up the link again please.

Comment: @SulimanSharif pointers and raw arrays are unsafe. Your programmay crash from a invalid index or a null pointer. ps. the complier can't generate codes for forwardScore[][][]. Only the last bracet may be left blank.